# Videos not loading in flash CS6 published to android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, video

I'm new to flash so I will try to write it down as clear as i can. I hope you can help me with this and thanks in advance.
I have a project that function like a brochure. Its just a compilation images, text and several videos with a very simple goto pages functions.
the images and text are already included in the fla file while the videos are in my project file directory and streamed from my local hard drive. I'm using the earlier version of flash video component and I'm using flash CS6.

My AS3 Script to load the videos

```
sp.source = SPContent;
sp.setSize(340, 335);

var VidBtn01 = MovieClip(sp.content).VidBtn01;
var VidBtn02 = MovieClip(sp.content).VidBtn02;

VidBtn01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick01);
VidBtn02.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick02);

UNOVid.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, stopMovie);
function stopMovie(e:Event=null)
{
UNOVid.stop();
}

function onClick01(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    UNOVid.source = "Video1.flv";
}
VidBtn01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick01);

function onClick02(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    UNOVid.source = "Video2.flv";
}
VidBtn02.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick02);
```

When test published in flash professional, the projects works really well. When Publishing for android and iOS, flash do not reveal any errors. Upon

testing the published apk and api files, then the problem arise.

Problem 1 Android: All buttons and navigation working, flash video component present but some videos canot be played.
Problem 2 iOS: All buttons and navigation working, videos not playing, cant really tell because flash video component is not being displayed.

All videos are flv 320x240 but of different duration and encoded using flash video encoder same settings. During packaging files included are the

projects swf, the flash video component's swf, the app.xml and all the videos included in the project. The .apk and .api file size is 1.02GB. I also tried

publishing without the videos just to see the file size and both the .apk and .api file is only 3.9mb. Also check the videos folder size in windows

properties, size is 1gb plus.

I checked the installed app on my iOS device using an app called iFile from cydia, all the videos are accounted for with the flash component.
For android upon checking the installed file it revealed and apk file and some .so file. You cant really see if the files are all in there. So I did a little

research and learned that if you change the .apk extension to .rar, you can extract the file in windows to inspect whats inside your published .apk

file. Upon doing sa I was able to see that all the files are accounted for.

I'm using for device testing a generic android tablet running 4.01 IceCreamSandwich and an iPad Air iOS7 jail broken.

My Question for ANDROID

1. How does android process the apk file, why was the apk files not extracted when installed on my device?
2. What might be the reason why some of the videos  cannot be played? Hardware Limitation perhaps, any idea?
3. Will there be a conflict with the New Versions of Android (jellybean/Kitkat) since adobe flash already stopped supporting android?

My Question for iOS

1. Why was the Flash Video Component missing? Is this a compatibility issue with iOS since the flash video component is an swf file?
   I assumed that packaging it would eliminate that issue considering that publishing air for ios includes adobe air in the package. If that's the case isthere another way to deliver the video on stage in iOS?
2. Is FLV video compatible with iOS if not what video compression should i use?

Lastly how can i publish to Android and iOS without the need to package it with the video. So the final .apk and .api file size is manageable.
Perhaps just adding the videos in a directory within he device's storage using the resolve path method. Can anyone share how i can do this?
Again thanks in advance to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have time for a complete answer right now. Here's a partial answer: 
You can't use .flv on iOS. You have to encode using the H.264 codec in an .mp4 file. Apple has more-or-less particular specs on the encoding. Look 'em up!

Also, in iOS you'll want to use the **StageVideo** class combined with the **Netstream** and **NetConnection** classes. StageVideo is a requirement for the GPU video processing on iOS devices. BUT when you're running your video code on a desktop machine, or when you're running video in AIR on desktop, you want to use the regular **Video** Class because you'll be rendering, usually, with the CPU.  So, usually, your code will have to test for the availability of GPU processing and then invoke one function for implementing THAT, or another function if only CPU processing is available.

Video (without components -- which you should forget!) sounds complicated, but it's not THAT complicated. It just takes a little time to learn. Suggestion: study here - http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=46 for the basics of the Video Class. Then read the Adobe AS3 reference on StageVideo.  Then come back here and ask more questions. You'll beat your head against a wall for a day or so, but then you'll really know how to handle video on, at least some mobile devices.

When you're testing on iOS don't forget to publish with GPU rendering.

I'm just learning AIR for Android myself so can't help you there.

Comment: Thanks Craig the site was indeed very helpfull